# React Hooks Issue When Calling useState

Tags: reactjs

I have the following React Todo component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const todo = props => {

  const inputState = useState('') // problem with this line 

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <input type="text" />
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

export default todo
```

When I run the app I get the following error in the browser:

```
./src/Todo.js
  Line 5:  React Hook "useState" is called in function "todo" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
```

I am using create-react-app to build my app and I am using the following versions of React.

```
  "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.0"
```

Comment: Arrgg! That was it. If you can post as answer I will accept it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to write your component name with a **capital** first letter for it to be seen as a Component.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Todo = props => {

  const inputState = useState('') // problem with this line 

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <input type="text" />
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

export default Todo
```

Comment: Right. Does it mean we will need to change every functional component name to use the power of the latest feature?

Comment: @sachinkumar It's not a new thing. Since the very beginning, you have to write component names with a capital first letter.

Comment: But I can be able to create a function based components in lowercase in react 16.8

Comment: @sachinkumar Technically, you always can, it's just a convention. But JSX will try to process lowercase identifier as html tags.